# How can I concatenate three layers in a Keras sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation

I would like to concatenate three layers in my Keras sequential model. Is there a way to do so? I would like to concatenate them along `axis=2`.

[Here is how the model summary looks like for now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vqEN.png)

Here is the code.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(seq_len, n_inputs)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(None, n_inputs,seq_len), filters=N_CONV_A, padding='same',kernel_size=F_CONV_A, strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(None, n_inputs,seq_len), filters=N_CONV_B, padding='same',kernel_size=F_CONV_B, strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(None, n_inputs,seq_len), filters=N_CONV_C, padding='same',kernel_size=F_CONV_C, strides=1, activation='relu'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate the layers". Do you mean you want to concatenate the output of the three layers?

Comment: Hi Aditya, yes I do. Sorry for not clarifying it earlier.

Comment: Simply sequential models, are limited to one input and one output, and as it's name suggests, you can arrange layers in sequential. If you have 3 layers in parallel and the same input, you should use Functional API or model subclassing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequential model cannot manage concatenation because the layers that are concatenated are computed *in parallel* with respect to its input.

In a sequential model the output of a layer becomes the input of the next layer, while the concatenation requires to use the same input for many layers.

In this situation you should use the [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) or [Model subclassing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models).

For example using the functional API the code becomes

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_inputs, seq_len))
convA = keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(None, n_inputs, seq_len),filters=N_CONV_A, padding='same',kernel_size=F_CONV_A, strides=1, activation='relu')
convB = keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(None, n_inputs, seq_len),filters=N_CONV_B, padding='same',kernel_size=F_CONV_B, strides=1, activation='relu')
convC = keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(None, n_inputs, seq_len),filters=N_CONV_C, padding='same',kernel_size=F_CONV_C, strides=1, activation='relu')
concat = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
out = concat([convA(inputs), convB(inputs), convC(inputs)])
```

Attention: `input_shape` in the your code is not consistent with the expected ones.